# Finding the angle between subspace and a vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Find the angle between the vector $x=(2,2,1,1)$ and the space formed by the linear combination of the vectors $a_1 = (3,4,-4,-1)$ and $a_2=(0,1,-1,2)$.

I found the vector $y=(3,1,3,1)$ that is perpendicular to  both $a_1$ and $a_2$. Then found the angle between $x$ and $y$:
$$\varphi = \arccos\frac{\langle x,y \rangle}{|x||y|}=\arccos\frac{3\sqrt 2}{5}$$
As the answer I took $\pi/2 - \varphi$. Is this correct?

---

**Update:** I found this [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3670407/find-the-angle-between-a-vector-and-a-linear-subspace-spanned-by-vectors) but could you please help me understand the difference between my solution and that in the link I provided? Why should we find an orthonormal basis as the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3670431/752069) states? It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (my original answer was incorrect)

To see why your solution is not correct, I will consider a simpler example.  Let $a_1 , a_2$ be such that $span\{ a_1 , a_2 \} = span \{ (1,0,0,0) , (0,1,0,0) \}$. Let $x=(0,0,1,0)$. Then any vector that is perpendicular to combinations of $a_1 , a_2$ is of the form $y = (0,0, y_3 , y_4)$.  I will show that your solution can lead to different answers:

- If you found that $y = (0,0,1,0)$, then $\cos \varphi = \langle y,x\rangle /(\|y \| \| x \|)=1$
- If you found that $y = (0,0,1,1)$, then $\cos \varphi = \langle y,x\rangle /(\|y \| \| x \|)=1/\sqrt{2}$

---

To see why the linked answer is correct, notice that they simply compute the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $span \{ a_1 , a_2 \}$.  Denote this projection $y$.  Then the angle between $x$ and $y$ is exactly what you are looking for.  Note that in order to compute the projection, you need an orthonormal basis (this is how projection is defined)

Comment: Ok, thanks! So, is the rest of the solution correct?

Comment: As long as the vector was indeed perpenicular to $a_1$ and $a_2$.  I assume you used cross product to find it, in which case rest of the solution is perfectly good

Comment: I found $y$ by solving the system 
$$\langle y,a_1 \rangle=0, \langle y,a_2 \rangle = 0$$

Comment: @VIVID sorry i was wrong.. Please see answer now

Comment: Nazim, thank you, I appreciate this.